# confirmation token Automatically generated NIL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an issue with an automatically generated token. In a model, I generate the token automatically using:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  before_create :generate_confirm_token

  def generate_confirm_token
    self.confirm_token = generate_token
  end

  def generate_token
    loop do
      token = SecureRandom.hex(10)
      break token unless User.where(confirm_token: token).exists?
    end
  end
```

After creating of user, the token is generated correctly, but the issue is in a controller:

```
class Companies::StudentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @company = Company.find(params[:company_id])
    @student = @company.students.create(student_params)
     raise @student.inspect
    if @student.save
      StudentMailer.with(student: @student).welcome_email.deliver_now
      redirect_to company_students_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

`student` contains `confirm_token` BUT in `params` the confirm token is empty.

[image]
I need the token in `params` because in the mailer  I use `Find_by(params[:confirm_token])`.

Here is how I use a `confirm_token` in my view. I assume I need the `confirm_token` in `params` so I have to have it in a view also:

```
  <%= f.hidden_field :confirm_token %>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using (https://github.com/heartcombo/devise)[Devise] and letting it handle all the user tokens for you?

Comment: Not sure if I understood the logic for Student model - should it generate token on creation as a User, or should it just save passed token? In inspect result I can see that `@student` has a token, so you can use it in mailer.

Comment: Please don't abuse font styles. If you put everything in bold it loses its purpose. "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)"

Answer (score 0):

The process which is described above is OK.
The issue was in mailer.

`student` should be in mailer created like this:

```
@student = params[:student]
```

but I did it like this:

```
@student = Student.find_by(confirm_token: :confirm_token)
```

Which is not correct according to the mailer documentation:

> Any key value pair passed to with just becomes the params for the
>   mailer action. So with(user: @user, account: @user.account) makes
>   params[:user] and params[:account] available in the mailer action.
>   Just like controllers have params.

Comment: Please don't create an answer to explain unless you intend for that answer to be the selected solution. If that is the intention please don't use "chatty" content. SO isn't a message board or a forum, it's more like an online reference book of programming questions and answers. Your "answer" is really a comment as you're trying to respond to everyone. Please go through the [Stack Overflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and all their linked pages.